# Hamiltonian particle system and its frequency domain

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-transform, hamiltonian-mechanics

I am interested in the following question.
So let suppose we have finite number of point particles on plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.
We can assume that every $j$ point is represented by Dirac delta function $\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_j)$.

Fourier transformation maps
$\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_j) \rightarrow e^{-2 \pi i (\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}_j) }$

Being applied to the whole system it leads to the following frequency value
$f (\vec{k}) = \sum_j e^{-2 \pi i (\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}_j)}$

The points are moving according to Hamiltonian dynamics which means frequency function changes over time. And it satisfies the following differential equation:

$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -2 \pi i \sum_j (\vec{p}_j \cdot \vec{k}_j) e^{-2 \pi i (\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}_j)}
$

Is there anything known in this field?
Like how to evaluate asymptotics of frequency domain $t \rightarrow \infty$?
I would really appreciate some references as paper or book.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transformed density $f(\mathbf{k},t)$ plays a central in dynamic light scattering. The classic text is by [Berne and Pecora](https://www.eng.uc.edu/~beaucag/Classes/Properties/Books/Bruce%20J.%20Berne,%20Robert%20Pecora%20-%20Dynamic%20Light%20Scattering_%20With%20Applications%20to%20Chemistry,%20Biology,%20and%20Physics-John%20Wiley%20&%20Sons,%20Inc.%20(2000).pdf) (B&P). The correlator
$$F(\mathbf{k},t)=\langle f(-\mathbf{k},0)f(\mathbf{k},t)\rangle$$
contains information on the Brownian motion of particles suspended in a fluid (see equation 5.4.2 in B&P). For non-interacting particles it decays as
$$F(\mathbf{k},t)=e^{-k^2 Dt},\;\;t>0,$$
with $D$ the diffusion constant.

<sub>*Personal note:* I started out my scientific life calculating how the decay is modified by [hydrodynamic interactions.](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/handle/1887/3297?solr_nav%5Bid%5D=c8c0787be1030bbacf92&solr_nav%5Bpage%5D=16&solr_nav%5Boffset%5D=8)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for good reference! One question: is there any known physical conditions which imply organization of particles with blue noise property?

Comment: you want a power density growing linearly with frequency? no idea if that is possible  for Hamiltonian dynamics/